# How to create a controller in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an app called blogger, the express app should have one route page and 2 controller pages. The routes/index.js should go to controllers (home->home.js) (blog->blog.js) but its giving me an error that I don't know how to fix. Thanks in advance.

app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

//error handler is here

module.exports = app;
```

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ctrlHome = require('../controllers/home');
var ctrlBlog = require('../controllers/blog');

router.get('/', ctrlHome.bHome);
router.get('/blogAdd', ctrlBlog.bAdd);
router.get('/bloList', ctrlBlog.bList);

module.exports = router;
```

controllers/home.js

```
module.express.bHome = function(req, res) {
          res.render('index', { title: 'Blog Home' });
```

controllers/blog.js

```
module.exports.bAdd = function(req, res){
                         res.render('blogAdd', { title: 'Blog Add' });
};

module.exports.bList = function(req, res){
                         res.render('blogList', { title: 'Blog List' });
};
```

The error is:

```
/home/bitnami/blogger/controllers/home.js:4
module.express.bHome = function(req, res) {
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'bHome' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bitnami/blogger/controllers/home.js:4:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bitnami/blogger/routes/index.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be module.express.bHome

Rather module.exports.bHome

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo.

Change `module.express.bHome` to `module.exports.bHome`

Comment: I've been looking at it for at least an hour now, thank you very much i can't believe it was that simple